# Ninject Configuration to work Unit of Work configuration for Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, ninject, unit-of-work

I am using unit of work design pattern to interact with the DB context in ASP.NET MVC application. I want to use UoW in order to use transactions for a Windows Service. What Ninject configuration should I use when I bind the DBContext?

Comment: Configure it to inject your DbContext into the UoW classes in transient scope

Answer (score 0):

First of, `DbContext` is a Unit of Work. There should be no need for you to implement one on top of it. Just in case you didn't know ;-)

---

You'll have to define your own transaction boundaries. There's no pre-defined scoping mechanism like 'InRequestScope` (except if you're handling WCF requests, then there would be, too).

In case you're creating an object-subtree per request you could use  'InCallScope()' or you can define your own transaction scoping mechanism and use 'InScope(ctx => scope object)´. Make sure the scope object implements `INotifyWhenDisposed`, otherwise the `DbContext` is not disposed of immediately.

If you're not creating an object-subtree per request then you'll need to use a factory to create the `DbContext` per transaction and pass it from method to method. As a factory you could just inject `Func<DbContext>` (this requires [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory))

Answer (score 0):

The [Ninject.Extensions.UnitOfWork](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.UnitOfWork) solves this problem.

Setup:

```
_kernel.Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InUnitOfWorkScope();
```

Usage:

```
using(UnitOfWorkScope.Create()){
    // resolves, async/await, manual TPL ops, etc    
}
```